# Trying to understand HMAC SHA256

Tags: t-sql, sha256, hmac

For an API I need to provide secured information hashed with the HMAC SHA256 protocol. I would like to prepare all my API requests in a stored procedure in an Azure SQL DB, so the hashing needs to take place in SQL. I'm not married to that idea, if there are better ways I can be flexible.

Currently I have the issue that I don't fully understand how different ways of creating the hash, can lead to different outcomes. For instance;

> **Linux CMD with OpenSSL**
>
> ```
> ~$ echo "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "key"
> ```
>
> (stdin)=
> 62b5378a72e18e8b220382be8a4fce0a341ab06afa6367fe664219713e11bb4d
>
> **PowerShell**
>
> ```
> $message = 'message'
>
> $secret = 'key'
>
> $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
>
> $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
>
> $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
>
> $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
>
> echo $signature
> ```
>
> bp7ym3X//Ft6uuUn1Y/a2y/kLnIZARl2kXNDBl9Y7Uo=
>
> **Online tool**
>
> https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output
> 6e9ef29b75fffc5b7abae527d58fdadb2fe42e7219011976917343065f58ed4a
>
> **My scalar function**
>
> Got the function from https://gist.github.com/rmalayter/3130462
>
> ```
> declare @query nvarchar(4000),
>         @secret nvarchar(500);
>
> set @query = 'message'
> set @secret = 'key' 
>
> select dbo.fn_HMAC('SHA2_256',cast(@query as varbinary(max)), CAST(@secret as varbinary(max)))
> ```
>
> 0x93552E8AB930FFCEE9E158A7EA5926A4F36025A1A0ED538763B26AF74147D299

So these 4 methods return 4 different Hashes. I know I need the Has as returned by OpenSSL ( first example ).

can you maybe help me understand why these options return different hashes and how to obtain the hash as generated by OpenSSL in Linux CMD?

Comment: Have you checked the lengths (in bytes) of the various messages? In TSQL you're using `NVarChar` which stores byte-pairs, not `VarChar` which uses bytes.

Comment: [Online-Convert](https://www.online-convert.com/result/fece7fb2-8517-4c0e-b9e4-a51b80330a32) shows that your results from PowersHell and FreeFormatter are the same, only differing in output formatting: base-64 vs. hexadecimal.

Comment: @HABO; Thank you for replying. I did try using varchar, I just also tried using a table with UTF-8 columns. but that doen not change the resulting Hash.

I did manage to get the same result from SQL! Using this Blog I managed to get the same results as PowerShell and that Online Tool

https://blog.greglow.com/2014/07/10/step-one-in-producing-shared-access-signatures-for-sql-server-data-files-in-azure-generating-a-sha2-256-hmac-hash-using-native-t-sql/

I missed the fact that those are in fact the same. Unfortunately that kind of proves my fear that the OpenSSL version is the odd one out.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! HABO was right it did have to do with an NVARCHAR variable in my script. Once replaced with a VARCHAR it worked!!!